# Overwriting "Print Screen" actions in linux without administrative rights

Tags: linux, screenshot, x11, keyboard-events, printscreen

### Disclaimer:

I am a bit of a Linux noob :(

### Problem:

I have an interesting problem that I could use some help with.  Essentially, I want to overwrite the default actions for the "Print Screen" button in Linux.  My reasons for doing so are that I have a homemade graphics card running attached to the computer and I'm trying to make a utility where I can capture what it is outputting to a separate monitor and send it back to the "host" computer.  For purposes here, I only want to know:  **How can I execute a script upon pressing the Print Screen button?**  Note that I cannot install xbindkeys or any other software.  Ideally I would like to be able to run a script to enable this behavior.

### Current work-around:

Currently, I have a .bashrc script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    export PATH=/home/username/bin:$PATH
```

In the **/home/username/bin** folder I have a script **"gnome-screenshot"** that, for now, just performs some arbitrary task (it actually does this:  **"cat /usr/share/icons/*/* > /dev/dsp"** -- try it!  It's fun!).

I am working on school computers, so I first CTRL-ALT-F5 to open a terminal login, login, then source .bashrc.  I then startx -- :1  to start a new X session.  Now, if I hit the PrintScreen button, it uses my gnome-screenshot, not the default screencapture program.

**Is there anyway to do this without all of the restarting X?  In short, is there a way to source my .bashrc script, or otherwise modify my PATH variable, *before or while* I login?**

### Another Approach:

I also tried, briefly, to xmodmap and the keycode to execute a script, but couldn't figure out how to tie them together.  I know the keycode (111) but can't figure out how to run a script on press.  I believe it might be possible to make a sort of binding using this but can't figure out how.

### Help!

I'd really appreciate some help or comments!

### (Edit):  Added Details About Distribution:

cat /etc/redhat-release  tells me:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I used XGrabKey on the root window, but am curiours to hear how you accomplished it

Comment: Truthfully I can't remember what we ended up doing!  4 years (almost exactly!) is too long.  :)

Answer (score 3):

`xmodmap` is not the tool you want; it cannot bind keys to programs, it binds physical keycodes to logical keysyms.  [`XGrabKey(3)`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKey.html) is what you're looking for.

Reading your shell dotfiles while starting the X session depends on the exact OS and desktop environment you're using (including version; there are 4 or 5 different ways you might need to use even considering only different Ubuntu versions with their stock desktops).

Comment: Great comment thank you!  I would upvote but I don't have 15 reputation yet :(

Comment: cat /proc/version reveals:  

Linux version 2.6.18-308.e15 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)

Any idea about establishing that PATH variable?

Comment: That's insufficient; `/etc/debian_version` might be more helpful if it's a Debian derivative, `/etc/redhat-release` if it's (even distantly) derived from Red Hat Linux.  And even so it's also a question of which desktop (KDE? Gnome? LXDE? other?) and version thereof.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Comment: Ok, I'll have to ask others to respond beyond this because I'm more familiar with Debian, Ubuntu, and SuSE so don't know the peculiarities of that platform well.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your replies!